# Select para pegar constraint de 2 colunas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu possuo uma tabela PESSOA que nela tenho o campo A e B que formam uma `UNIQUE`.

Eu rodo este select para retornar o nome da `constraint`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL.CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col
WHERE Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
AND Col.Table_Name = 'PESSOA'
AND COL.COLUMN_NAME IN ('A','B')
AND Tab.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'UNIQUE'
```

O problema é que caso haja uma `UNIQUE` individual para ambos os campos é retornado também. Como faço pro select retornar só a `constraint` que é associada as colunas A e B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COL.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col
WHERE Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
AND Col.Table_Name = 'PESSOA'
AND COL.COLUMN_NAME IN ('A','B')
AND Tab.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'UNIQUE
GROUP BY COL.CONSTRAINT_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Trará os casos de mais de uma coluna.

Comment: Obrigado, show, preciso.